# Access Jenkins from the Internet on Windows

Tags: java, jenkins, dns, continuous-integration, ip

I am new to Jenkins and I have been trying to access my Jenkins server from the Internet, so that you can access it from anywhere.

I set up a no-ip DNS server to be able to bind my public ip and create a Hostname which I added Jenkins URL, but I can't access it. Do I have to add any additional configuration to Jenkins? Could someone guide me how to access it? I am really new to this.

Note: Adding port 8080 to my firewall allows me to access my localhost from any device I have on my network.

Note 2: I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if it's accessible with IP and port from the Internet. If it's not you should configure your network to allow the port and route it to the server.

Your network router has to be configured to route the incoming requests on the given port from the Internet to your server. Or your server must have a public IP assigned.

Open a windows command prompt, and execute command `ipconfig` to see the IP addresses assigned to the system, if you don't see your public IP here that means your system is behind a router, and without proper router configuration this system can't be accessed from the Internet.

If your system receives its IP from a router, that router must be accessible from the Internet, meaning that router should be directly connecting to the Internet, and it must have "Port Forwarding" feature through which it can be configured to forward the incoming requests to a host in its network. Or if you can connect to the Internet directly without a network router from your system it will have a publicly accessible IP address.

Comment: Hi @user15117826, I understand. In case I can't configure it since I don't have a public IP, is there another alternative? https://ibb.co/tBFRyC3